# Deep CNN-BLSTM network's loss and cost suddenly start fluctuating - is this normal?

Tags: deep-learning, accuracy, loss-functions, tensorflow, cross-entropy

I have a CNN feeding into a BLSTM feeding into a fully connected layer trying to do classification. I've noticed some odd behaviour approx. 70% into my epoch - the accuracy and cost start fluctuating wildly. See graphs below.

- Framework: TensorFlow v1.0.0
- Optimiser: tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer
- Cost function: Cross-Entropy
- Fluctuation starts: Step ~7600 Total steps: 11200

#### Accuracy Graph

[image: Accuracy Graph]

#### Cost Graph

[image: Cost Graph]
*Note that the y-axis is log scale for the cost graph*

**Is this normal?**

Comment: I'd add more links but I don't have the reputation to do so.